# BOB Nutz for a solid nutted 9mm axle from Sturmey Archer

Tags: sturmey-archer

I'm looking for BOB Nutz that will fit [this 9mm Sturmey Archer axle](https://www.sturmey-archer.com/files/catalog/files/327/SPECIFICATIONS%20-%20REAR%20DRUM%20BRAKE%20HUBS.pdf).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking for where to buy one? Or are you asking for how to tell if one is compatible? Something else?

Comment: I'm interested in buying one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Table 1 of the BOB Nutz instruction manual:

[image]

and to Campfire Cycling, an online store that sells BOB Nutz:

[image]

There would be no BOB Nutz compatible with a 9 mm axle.

Comment: Thanks!  It looks like I'm going to have to go with the Shimano Roller brake instead.

Comment: @XERXEN You are very welcome. Make sure to take a look at the BOB Nutz instructions manual for more information about compatible axles. There are other important measurements such as the number of threads per inch (TPI), the minimum and maximum axle length and the exposed axle length.

Answer (score 1):

Something doesn't smell right here. The data sheet is calling that axle 9mm, but 9mm rear axles don't really exist. They would have awkward up and down slop in the dropout. I think what's going is that it's a 9.5mm x 26tpi thread (same as 3/8"x26) and for whatever reason that data sheet is calling it 9mm. (It could also be 24tpi, but that size never really goes along with freewheels, only coaster/IGH.) Note that Sturmey is Sunrace and this kind of thing does happen in documentation.

There are some more or less antique bikes that use smaller size rear axle diameters, but I don't think that's what this hub is for.

Edit: Here is a wholesaler (where shops and dealers would look to confirm compatibility before buying) listing this as a 3/8" axle hub.

[image]

Comment: I could not find more detailed specs for the axle dimension on the manufacturer's website. Would contacting Sturmey-Archer customer support be a next good step for XERXEN to confirm what you think?

Comment: @olliebulle Asking the manufacturer directly is a good first step to almost every component-specific question on this site :). But I'm pretty confident. Rear hubs can't be literally 9mm and work on non-weird dropouts.